# Background Application unable to display UI when receive push notification

Tags: blackberry, push-notification, listener, background-application

Here is my full push notification listener.

```java
public class MyApp extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PushAgent pa = new PushAgent();
        pa.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
}
```

Is this class extended correctly?

```java
public class PushAgent extends Application {
private static final String PUSH_PORT = "32023";
private static final String BPAS_URL = "http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com";
private static final String APP_ID = "2727-c55087eR3001rr475448i013212a56shss2";
private static final String CONNECTION_SUFFIX = ";deviceside=false;ConnectionType=mds-public";

public static final long ID = 0x749cb23a75c60e2dL;

private MessageReadingThread messageReadingThread;

public PushAgent() {
    if (!CoverageInfo.isCoverageSufficient(CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_BIS_B)) {
        return;
    }
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {
        return;
    }
    messageReadingThread = new MessageReadingThread();
    messageReadingThread.start();
    registerBpas();
}

private static class MessageReadingThread extends Thread {

    private boolean running;
    private ServerSocketConnection socket;
    private HttpServerConnection conn;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private PushInputStream pushInputStream;

    public MessageReadingThread() {
        this.running = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        String url = "http://:" + PUSH_PORT + CONNECTION_SUFFIX;

        try {
            socket = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open(url);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        while (running) {
            try {
                Object o = socket.acceptAndOpen();
                conn = (HttpServerConnection) o;
                inputStream = conn.openInputStream();
                pushInputStream = new MDSPushInputStream(conn, inputStream);
                PushMessageReader.process(pushInputStream, conn);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (running) {
                    running = false;
                }
            } finally {
                close(conn, pushInputStream, null);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void close(Connection conn, InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    if (os != null) {
        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

private String formRegisterRequest(String bpasUrl, String appId,
        String token) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bpasUrl);
    sb.append("/mss/PD_subReg?");
    sb.append("serviceid=").append(appId);
    sb.append("&osversion=").append(DeviceInfo.getSoftwareVersion());
    sb.append("&model=").append(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName());
    if (token != null && token.length() > 0) {
        sb.append("&").append(token);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

private void registerBpas() {
    final String registerUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID, null)
            + CONNECTION_SUFFIX;
    Object theSource = new Object() {
        public String toString() {
            return "Oriental Daily";
        }
    };

    NotificationsManager.registerSource(ID, theSource,
            NotificationsConstants.IMPORTANT);

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                HttpConnection httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector
                        .open(registerUrl);
                InputStream is = httpConnection.openInputStream();
                String response = new String(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is));
                close(httpConnection, is, null);

                String nextUrl = formRegisterRequest(BPAS_URL, APP_ID,
                        response) + CONNECTION_SUFFIX;
                HttpConnection nextHttpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector
                        .open(nextUrl);
                InputStream nextInputStream = nextHttpConnection
                        .openInputStream();
                response = new String(
                        IOUtilities.streamToBytes(nextInputStream));
                close(nextHttpConnection, is, null);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
}
}
```

This is the `process`;

```java
public class PushMessageReader {
private static final String MESSAGE_ID_HEADER = "Push-Message-ID";
private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT = "text";
private static final String MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE = "image";

private static final int MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH = 10;
private static String[] messageIdHistory = new String[MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH];
private static byte historyIndex;

private static byte[] buffer = new byte[15 * 1024];
private static byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[10 * 1024];

public static final long ID = 0x749cb23a75c60e2dL;
public static Bitmap popup = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon_24.png");

private PushMessageReader() {
}

public static void process(PushInputStream pis, Connection conn) {
    try {
        HttpServerConnection httpConn;

        if (conn instanceof HttpServerConnection) {
            httpConn = (HttpServerConnection) conn;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Can not process non-http pushes, expected HttpServerConnection but have "
                            + conn.getClass().getName());
        }

        String msgId = httpConn.getHeaderField(MESSAGE_ID_HEADER);
        String msgType = httpConn.getType();
        String encoding = httpConn.getEncoding();

        if (!alreadyReceived(msgId)) {
            byte[] binaryData;

            if (msgId == null) {
                msgId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }

            if (msgType.indexOf(MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT) >= 0) {
                int size = pis.read(buffer);
                binaryData = new byte[size];
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, binaryData, 0, size);

                NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(ID, 0, null,
                        null);
                processTextMessage(buffer);
            } else if (msgType.indexOf(MESSAGE_TYPE_IMAGE) >= 0) {
                int size = pis.read(buffer);

                if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("base64")) {
                    Base64InputStream bis = new Base64InputStream(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer, 0, size));
                    size = bis.read(imageBuffer);
                }

                binaryData = new byte[size];
                System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, binaryData, 0, size);
            }
        }
        pis.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        PushAgent.close(conn, pis, null);
    }
}

private static boolean alreadyReceived(String id) {
    if (id == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Arrays.contains(messageIdHistory, id)) {
        return true;
    }

    messageIdHistory[historyIndex++] = id;

    if (historyIndex >= MESSAGE_ID_HISTORY_LENGTH) {
        historyIndex = 0;
    }
    return false;
}

private static void processTextMessage(final byte[] data) {
    synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {

        UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();

        GlobalDialog screen = new GlobalDialog("New Notification",
                "Article ID : " + new String(data), new String(data));

        ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
    }
}

static class GlobalDialog extends PopupScreen implements
        FieldChangeListener {
    ButtonField mOKButton = new ButtonField("OK", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK
            | FIELD_HCENTER);
    String data = "";

    public GlobalDialog(String title, String text, String data) {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager());
        this.data = data;

        add(new LabelField(title));
        add(new SeparatorField(SeparatorField.LINE_HORIZONTAL));
        add(new LabelField(text, DrawStyle.HCENTER));

        mOKButton.setChangeListener(this);
        add(mOKButton);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (mOKButton == field) {
            try {
                ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch(
                        "OrientalDailyBB");
                ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().postGlobalEvent(
                        ID, 0, 0, data, null);

                ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry
                        .getInstance();
                reg.unregister();

                close();
            } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

In this project, I checked **Auto-run on startup** so that this background app listener will run all the time and set the **start tier** to 7 in the BB App Descriptor.

However, it cannot display the popup `Dialog`, but I can see the device has received the push notification.

After the dialog popup and user click **OK** will start the `OrientalDailyBB` project and display the particular `MainScreen`.

**FYI**: The listener priority is higher than the `OrientalDailyBB` project because it is a background application. So when I install `OrientalDailyBB`, it will install this listener too. It happened because this listener is not in the `OrientalDailyBB` project folder, but is in a different folder. I did separate them to avoid the background application being terminated when the user quits from `OrientalDailyBB`.

Comment: are you sure, u getting push notifications ?

Comment: refer this http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/07/push-notification-in-blackberry.html

Comment: Tested with install 2 jad files. When only 1 jad file then cannot

Comment: what you mean by "Tested with install 2 jad files" ?

Comment: download and install push.jad and orientaldailybb.jad then no problem.

Comment: download and install orientaldailybb.jad (using updatejad.exe to merge 2 jad) then failed

Comment: @AlanLai I am having similar issues. I have posted my question [here][1] [http://%5B1%5D:%20http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274327/push-message-not-received-in-device]:  as well. Do you mind sharing your executable file for the client side App. The above code that you posted will only run in background? Were you able to resolve your issue of receiving push messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this is a threading problem. `pushGlobalScreen` is a message you could try to use with `invokeLater`.

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
  }
});
```

you could try to push the application to the foreground too.