# Push message not received in device

Tags: php, .net, blackberry, push-notification, server-push

I am struggling for long with push messaging in BlackBerry. I am able to register successfully for push messaging with a returned code of `rc=200`. However, when I run the server side code, be it in PHP or .Net, I get a successful returned code but the device never receives the message.

My PHP code is as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // APP ID provided by RIM
$appid = '3385-xxxxxxxxxxx';
// Password provided by RIM
$password = 'xxxxxx';

//Deliver before timestamp
$deliverbefore = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+35 minutes'));

//An array of address must be in PIN format or "push_all"
$addresstosendto[] = 'xxxx';

$addresses = '';
foreach ($addresstosendto as $value) {
$addresses .= '<address address-value="' . $value . '"/>';
}

// create a new cURL resource
$err = false;
$ch = curl_init();
$messageid = microtime(true);

$data = '--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm'. "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n\r\n" .
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN" "http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/pap_2.1.dtd">
<pap>
<push-message push-id="' . $messageid . '" deliver-before-timestamp="' . $deliverbefore . '" source-reference="' . $appid . '">'
. $addresses .
'<quality-of-service delivery-method="confirmed"/>
</push-message>
</pap>' . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm' . "\r\n" .
'Content-Type: text/plain' . "\r\n" .
'Push-Message-ID: ' . $messageid . "\r\n\r\n" .
stripslashes('r') . "\r\n" .
'--mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm--' . "\n\r";

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest");//"https://cp3385.pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Hallgren Networks BB Push Server/1.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $appid . ':' . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=mPsbVQo0a68eIL3OAxnm; type=application/xml", "Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2", "Connection: keep-alive"));

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
echo $xmldata = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

//Start parsing response into XML data that we can read and output
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xmldata, $vals);
$errorcode = xml_get_error_code($p);
if ($errorcode > 0) {
echo xml_error_string($errorcode);
$err = true;
}
xml_parser_free($p);

echo 'Our PUSH-ID: ' . $messageid . "<br \>\n";
if (!$err && $vals[1]['tag'] == 'PUSH-RESPONSE') {
echo 'PUSH-ID: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['PUSH-ID'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'REPLY-TIME: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['REPLY-TIME'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Response CODE: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Response DESC: ' . $vals[2]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \> \n";
} else {
echo '<p>An error has occured</p>' . "\n";
echo 'Error CODE: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['CODE'] . "<br \>\n";
echo 'Error DESC: ' . $vals[1]['attributes']['DESC'] . "<br \>\n";
}


?>
```

My .NET code is as follows:

```
public bool pushToWidget(string pushedMessage, string pushPin)
        {
            String BESAddress = "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest";
            String BESWebserverListenPort = "33074";
            String widgetNotificationUrl = "https://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com/mss/PD_pushRequest";
            String pushUserName = "xxxx@xxx.com";
            String pushPassword = "xxx@xxx";
            String pushPort = "33074 ";
            string Boundary = "Boundary ";
            String ID = "3385-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            //String pushPin = "xxxxxxxx";
            string DeliverBefore = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60).ToString("s", 

System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "Z";
            Response.Write(DeliverBefore);
            bool success = true;
            StringBuilder Data = new StringBuilder();
            Data.AppendLine("--" + Boundary);
            Data.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
            Data.AppendLine("");
            Data.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
            Data.AppendLine("<!DOCTYPE pap PUBLIC \"-//WAPFORUM//DTD PAP 2.1//EN\">");
            Data.AppendLine("<pap>");
            Data.AppendLine("<push-message push-id=" + (char)34 + ID + (char)34 + " deliver-before-timestamp=" + 

(char)34 + DeliverBefore + (char)34 + " source-reference=" + (char)34 + pushUserName + (char)34 + ">");
            Data.AppendLine("<address address-value=\"" + pushPin + "\"/>");
            Data.AppendLine("<quality-of-service delivery-method=\"unconfirmed\"/>");
            Data.AppendLine("</push-message>");
            Data.AppendLine("</pap>");
            Data.AppendLine("--" + Boundary);
            Data.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/plain");
            Data.AppendLine("Push-Message-ID: " + ID);
            Data.AppendLine("");
            Data.AppendLine(pushedMessage);
            Data.AppendLine("--" + Boundary + "--");
            Data.AppendLine("");
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToString());

            Stream requestStream = null;
            HttpWebResponse HttpWRes = null;
            HttpWebRequest HttpWReq = null;

            try
            {
                //http://<BESName>:<BESPort>/push?

//String DESTINATTION="<299A7C32/EMAIL>&PORT=<PushPort>&REQUESTURI=/"
                // Build the URL to define our connection to the BES.
                string httpURL = BESAddress + ":" + BESWebserverListenPort
                    + "/push?DESTINATION=" + pushPin + "&PORT=" + pushPort
                    + "&REQUESTURI=/";

                //make the connection
                HttpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpURL);
                HttpWReq.Method = ("POST");
                //add the headers nessecary for the push
                HttpWReq.ContentType = "text/plain";
                HttpWReq.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                // ******* Test this *******
                HttpWReq.Headers.Add("X-Rim-Push-Id", pushPin + "~" + DateTime.Now); //"~" +pushedMessage +
                HttpWReq.Headers.Add("X-Rim-Push-Reliability", "application-preferred");
                HttpWReq.Headers.Add("X-Rim-Push-NotifyURL", (widgetNotificationUrl + pushPin + "~" + pushedMessage 

+ "~" + DateTime.Now).Replace(" ", ""));

                // *************************

                HttpWReq.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(pushUserName, pushPassword);
                Console.WriteLine(pushedMessage);
                requestStream = HttpWReq.GetRequestStream();
                //Write the data from the source
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                //get the response
                HttpWRes = (HttpWebResponse)HttpWReq.GetResponse();
                String response = HttpWRes.ToString();

                //if the MDS received the push parameters correctly it will either respond with okay or accepted
                if (HttpWRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || HttpWRes.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
                {
                    success = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    success = false;
                }
                //Close the streams

                HttpWRes.Close();
                requestStream.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                success = false;
            }

            return success;
        }
```

I am running the following code in my App to listen for incoming message:

```
public static void process(PushInputStream pis, Connection conn) {
        System.out.println("Reading incoming push message ...");

        try {

            HttpServerConnection httpConn;
            if (conn instanceof HttpServerConnection) {
                httpConn = (HttpServerConnection) conn;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can not process non-http pushes, expected HttpServerConnection but have "
                        + conn.getClass().getName());
            }

            String msgId = httpConn.getHeaderField(MESSAGE_ID_HEADER);
            String msgType = httpConn.getType();
            String encoding = httpConn.getEncoding();

            System.out.println("Message props: ID=" + msgId + ", Type=" + msgType + ", Encoding=" + encoding);


            boolean accept = true;
            if (!alreadyReceived(msgId)) {
                byte[] binaryData;

                if (msgId == null) {
                    msgId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }

                if (msgType == null) {
                    System.out.println("Message content type is NULL");
                    accept = false;
                } else if (msgType.indexOf(MESSAGE_TYPE_TEXT) >= 0) {
                    // a string
                    int size = pis.read(buffer);
                    binaryData = new byte[size];
                    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, binaryData, 0, size);   

                    PushMessage message = new PushMessage(msgId, System.currentTimeMillis(), binaryData, true, true );
                    String text = new String( message.getData(), "UTF-8" );


                     try{
                            final Dialog screen = new Dialog(Dialog.D_OK_CANCEL, " "+text,
                                    Dialog.OK,
                                    //mImageGreen.getBitmap(),
                                    null, Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
                            final UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();
                            Application.getApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    NotificationsManager.triggerImmediateEvent(0x749cb23a76c66e2dL, 0, null, null);
                                    ui.pushGlobalScreen(screen, 0, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);

                                }
                            });
                            screen.setDialogClosedListener(new MyDialogClosedListener());
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }


                    // TODO report message
                }  else {
                    System.out.println("Unknown message type " + msgType);
                    accept = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Received duplicate message with ID " + msgId);
            }
            pis.accept();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to process push message: " + e);
        }
    }
```

The above is part of the App code that is run to read the incoming message. I have posted the server side codes in detail as I am struggling with Push Messaging for a very long time and would appreciate if somebody can guide me in the right direction. Considering the fact that I am getting a "success" returned code from the server side code, could the issue be in listening and processing the message at the front end? I can share the client side App on request. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open socket connection in order to listen to incoming push. Here is the runnable class which you can use to open socket connection. Your process function can be called once you receive the incoming push message.

You can call using -

```
MessageReadingThread messageReadingThread = new MessageReadingThread();
Thread oThread = new Thread(messageReadingThread);
oThread.start();


/**
 * Thread that processes incoming connections through
 * {@link PushMessageReader}.
 */
private class MessageReadingThread implements Runnable
{
private final BIS_CONNECTION_SUFFIX = ";ConnectionType=mds-public";


private final String CONNECTION_SUFFIX = ";deviceside=false";

    /** Flag indicating Listening thread is running or not */
    private boolean bRunning;

    /** ServerSocketConnection instance to Listen for incoming push message */
    private ServerSocketConnection oSocket;


    private HttpServerConnection oHttpServerConnection;


    private InputStream oInputStream;


    private MDSPushInputStream oMDSPushInputStream; // PushInputStream

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    public void run()
    {
        String strUrl = "http://:" + PUSH_PORT + CONNECTION_SUFFIX + BIS_CONNECTION_SUFFIX;
        try
        {
            oSocket = (ServerSocketConnection) Connector.open(strUrl);
            m_bIsPortOpen = true;
            bRunning = true;
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // can't open the port, probably taken by another application
            fnStopRunning();
        }
        while (bRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                Object object = oSocket.acceptAndOpen();
                oHttpServerConnection = (HttpServerConnection) object;
                oInputStream = oHttpServerConnection.openInputStream();
                oMDSPushInputStream = new MDSPushInputStream(
                        oHttpServerConnection, oInputStream);
                process(oMDSPushInputStream,
                        oHttpServerConnection, app);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Failed to read push message
                bRunning = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                close(null, oInputStream, null);
                close(oHttpServerConnection, oMDSPushInputStream, null);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop running.
     */
    private void fnStopRunning()
    {
        bRunning = false;
        m_bIsPortOpen = false;
        close(oSocket, null, null);
    }

            /**
 * Safely closes connection and streams.
 */
private void close(Connection oConnection, InputStream oInputStream,
        OutputStream oOutputStream)
{
    if (oOutputStream != null)
    {
        try
        {
            oOutputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    if (oInputStream != null)
    {
        try
        {
            oInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
    if (oConnection != null)
    {
        try
        {
            oConnection.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```